# Router Security Warning in Logs

Tags: router

I'm getting regular attacks

```
2020-07-29 14:44:42 Security Warning ‭Intrusion -> SRC=80.227.225.108 DST=(my ip here) LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=63607 PROTO=TCP SPT=52363 DPT=1433 WIN‭
```

it's every 10 mins as I can see

I changed wifi password and made it hidden AP and the attacks still coming.

I even disconnected all devices and the logs keep getting this attack

Should I be worried?

```
2020-07-29 14:54:05 Security Warning ‭Intrusion -> SRC=45.129.33.22 DST=(my ip here) LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=40337 PROTO=TCP SPT=42068 DPT=3378 WINDO‭
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your wifi. So changing the password, hiding the AP, or disconnecting devices won't do a thing.

Comment: Is `156.218.255.222` your public IP? Do you have services on your router on ports 3378 and 1433?

Comment: yes this is my ip and i dont have any open ports for any services

Comment: Ultimately, you're asking us to explain all the different terminology used by your router's logs and what each attack type means. We are not going to go through all that. Your router's manual should help, and you can look up a lot of the terms yourself. The primary thing to notice is that each line is a `warning` not an `alert`.

Comment: I'm making this a duplicate of the question that first caught your attention because the answers are the same for you. This is normal, you are not being targetted, and there are a wide range of "attacks" that the log is reporting.

Answer (score 1):

It means you're connected to the Internet.

Random port scans and various other attacks are a more or less continuous occurrence for any device connected to the internet.

It's merely noise, and there's little reason to log dropped packets for normal residential users. It provides no value.

Comment: we need to finish ipv6 migration.  then it will be functionally impossible to enumerate address spaces for random scanning

Comment: Yeah, but it's not a real problem at present either. You shouldn't rely on security through obscurity anyway...

Comment: _"Welcome to the internet"_

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you don't have an endpoint or IoT device that is exposed in public.
It is pretty much normal nowadays seeing this kinds of traffic on the internet.
Bots or even threat actors are looking for open ports/services to be exploited.
If your router/firewall is state-full just explicitly block all incoming connections if you don't have any use-cases to expose an endpoint on your network, and allow all outbound connections.
This has nothing to do with your AP/WiFi.
You should be worried if an exploit was successful.